# Exact statement of the Radon-Nikodym Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I am a bit confused about the exact statement of the Radon-Nikodym Theorem. Suppose that in the usual setup, $v \ll u$. Does it require **both $v$ and $u$** to be sigma-finite, or **only $u$** to be sigma finite for the theorem to hold?

Answer (score 3):

You need both measures to be $\sigma$-finite. Suppose you have the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets on $[0,1]$ and let $\mu$ be the counting measure. The only set of measure zero with respect to $\mu$ is the empty set, so every measure is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and you can show that there is no nonnegative Lebesgue measurable function $f$ on $[0,1]$ for which 
$$
m(E)=\int_Ef\,d\mu
$$
where $E$ is any Lebesgue measurable set on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Please clarify one thing. In your answer, the counting measure mu is not sigma finite, so I cannot see how that answers my question. Actually, I am looking for a counterexample, where only mu is sigma finite, nu is absolutely continuous w.r.t mu, but not sigma finite, and the Radon Nikodym Theorem fails.

Comment: You need both measures to be $\sigma$-finite. The counting measure is not $\sigma$-finite and every other measure $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. In particular, the Lebesgue measure is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. So if the Radon-Nikodym result holds in this case, we should be able to find a Lebesgue measurable function such that $m(E)=\int_Ef\,d\mu$, but this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Only $u$ must be $\sigma$-finite. $v$ can be any (signed) measure. The result is proved in Section 2.2 in Ash and Doleans-Dade's book *Probability and Measure Theory* (2nd edition, 2000).

As a simple illustration, let $\Omega$ be some set and consider the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$. Suppose $u(\Omega) = 1$, $u(\emptyset) = 0$, $v(\Omega) = \infty$ and $v(\emptyset) = 0$. Obviously $u$ is $\sigma$-finite, $v$ is not $\sigma$-finite, and $v$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $u$. We can express $v(A) = \int_A g d\mu$, $A \in \mathcal{F}$, where $g = \infty$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $v$ w.r.t. $u$.

The Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem requires both measures to be $\sigma$-finite.